# Can I log visitors to website with a helper class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

I have an ASP.NET website hosted in-house server. My website doesn't have any way to track all the visitors. Is there any way to track / get log of all the external IP addresses of visitors who have visited / currently visiting my website ? By google, i found out that IIS keeps a log and i check the log here: C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1, but I don't have that control over my IIS per my hosting, can I write a helper class in a dll that just sits on my server and logs the ip of every Ip that comes in? The particular server doesn't serve any webpages, It's just a directory listing of images and text documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either ADSI scripting, or WMI to grab the data on the remote WebServer,

or possibly better -- [configure IIS to log data on a remote server](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0b56f0c2-5043-48a6-9564-2de0cc29c81d.mspx?mfr=true), perhaps your server.